# Simpler way to draw a list of a compound values with requirements of uniqueness and completeness?

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

Given an object I'm trying to construct:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass    

@dataclass
class Thing:
    thing_id: str
    a: int
    b: float
    # other attributes
```

For property-based testing I need to generate lists of `Thing` such that

- `item_id` is unique over the list
- `a` and `b` are paired values from a list `[(a0, b0), (a1, b1), ...]`
- from that list of `(a, b)` every value is drawn at least once

This is what I've come up with:

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st

def thing_lists(ab):
    # ab = [(a0, b0), (a1, b1), ...]
    vals = (
        # list that has at least all values from ab
        st.lists(st.sampled_from(ab))
        .flatmap(lambda sample: st.permutations(sample + ab))
        # add ids
        .flatmap(
            # get unique ids
            lambda abs: st.lists(
                st.text(), min_size=len(abs), max_size=len(abs), unique=True
            # zip with abs
            ).map(lambda ids: [(id, *ab) for id, ab in zip(ids, abs)])
        )
    )
    return vals.flatmap(
        lambda idabs: st.tuples(
            *[
                st.builds(
                    Thing,
                    st.just(id), 
                    st.just(a), 
                    st.just(b),
                    # other attributes by free choice of hypothesis
                )
                for (id, a, b) in idabs
            ]
        ).map(list)
    )
```

This works but it's a bit convoluted drawing a tuple and then mapping that over to a list; am I missing a different technique that's clearer about what's going on?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output? What does `list_of_things = [Thing(i,ab[0],ab[1]) for i,ab in enumerate(ab)]`  not give you, for instance?

Comment: If code is already working maybe[codereview.se] is more suitable? (read help center before asking)

Comment: @JeffUK it doesn't give me (a) more than just the minimum number of values, (b) free(er) choice over other attributes, which are important in the context of property-based testing. Edited to add that context to the question, thanks.

Comment: @user202729 the question's more about how to (better) use this particular tool, which seems more in-line with the questions I see here than there. I did think about asking the broader how and then answering with my could-be-improved answer.

Answer (score 1):

That looks basically reasonably to me - it's pretty grungy, but mostly because of your requirements.  I'd also try

```
vals = st.lists(
    st.tuples(st.text(), st.sampled_from(ab)),
    min_size=len(ab),
    unique_by=lambda x: x[0],
).filter(lambda ls: {x for _, x in ls}.issuperset(ab))
```

but obviously that filter is going to be a tough constraint if `ab` is long, so I'd only expect a perf win if it's short (but measure!).

If this *does* work, you'll get faster and sometimes better shrinking than the above; inlining the `builds()` part to make the generation of each list element fully local would improve this even further but might require a new constructor.  None of this is worth sacrificing readability for, though!

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by inlining `builds()` to make generation of each list element fully local, could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: If you can arrange things so that *everything* is inside a single `st.lists()` strategy, then Hypothesis can swap around elements (etc).  This is neat, but probably not applicable to your problem :/